# function not working OnClientUploadStart="UploadStart"?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

Hi all i am working on ajax fileupload here everything is working right but the 
function not working

```
OnClientUploadStart="UploadStart"
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here, could you please check and please help
to work on it? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code, please check:

```
<div>
     <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

  <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1"    AllowedFileTypes="pdf"   
   MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" OnClientUploadStart="UploadStart" runat="server"/>
    </div>
```

Here I am calling the function but it's not firing please check what i am doing wrong here:

```
<script language="javascript">
        function UploadStart(sender, args) {
            alert("Started:" + args.get_fileName());
            return false;
        }


    </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be something with function visibility. How is this function added to the page? Have you verified it exists in the final markup?

Comment: thanks for reply i had gone through u can check here              http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using the following, it broke after the alert popped up because I am  not handling where to upload the file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc2" %>
    <script lang="javascript">
        function UploadStart(sender, args) {
            alert("Started:" + sender._filesInQueue[0]._fileName);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <cc2:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></cc2:ToolkitScriptManager>

  <cc2:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1"    AllowedFileTypes="pdf"   
   MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" OnClientUploadStart="UploadStart" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```